# Помогите разобраться с Looper

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я создал свой поток

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;
      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();
          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // ...
              }
          };
          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

Потом в классе Activity запускаю его

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyThread t = new MyThread();
    t.start();
  }
```

Как я понимаю, так как я создал MyThread  в UI потоке, то и `Looper` будет из UI потока. Верно?

А если создам произвольный класс и там запущу поток?

```
class SomeClass {
     SomeClass() {
           MyThread t = new MyThread();
           t.start();
     }
}
```

Тут `Looper` уже не UI потока будет?
Я знаю, что есть HandlerThread, я просто не до конца догоняю как работает `Looper` и хочу разобраться а этом

Comment: Для начала прочитайте про потоки, вы Looper создаете внутри Thread (потока), что бы внутри потока что то запустить из UI потока нужно выполнить runOnUiThread

Comment: Нет, сообщения будут обрабатываться к контексте MyThread, который никак не зависит от потока, в котором будет создан. MyThread будет всегда "сам себе поток".

Comment: Если вам нужен Handler для UI-thread: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui